# Selecting id with difference betwen dates in same row being less than 30 days, but without new date in different row

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this

```
id plan_id cancel_date paid_date
9     2    2015-08-05  2014-09-13
10    2    2015-09-08  2015-09-03
10    3    NULL        2015-09-10
11    3    NULL        2015-09-13
14    3    2015-09-28  2015-09-14
```

And I would like to select ids where there is a less than 30 days difference between cancel_date and paid_date (for a given plan), and they didn't acquired a new plan in less than 30 days.

In this case, this would mean returning id 14 only.

Update:
Whenever a user buy a new plan, we insert it to the table, with a different paid_date (paid_date is the date that the plan was acquired the first time).

Comment: how do you define a new plan?

Comment: Hi @DarkKnight, I updated my question with a definition of new plan. Please, see if it answers your question. Thanks.